# Getting error MediaStream is not a constructor while using Npm recordrtc

Tags: node.js, reactjs, stream, webrtc, video-streaming

I have developed a console-based p2p nodejs application that receives streams and creates mp4 video files. I have streams Object and use the following npm to record streams. https://www.npmjs.com/package/recordrtc.

```
let recorder = new RecordRTCPromisesHandler(stream, {
type: 'video'
});
recorder.startRecording();
const sleep = m => new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, m));
await sleep(3000);
await recorder.stopRecording();
let blob = await recorder.getBlob();
invokeSaveAsDialog(blob);
```

Unfortunately, when recording.startrecording() is executed, I get the following error. `TypeError: MediaStream is not a constructor`

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c0var.png)